# Decent and affordable setup to record slamming doors, thumping

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, field-recording, setup, low-budget

I would like to record evidence of annoying sounds from downstair apartment (Please no judgment, legal or diplomatic advices). I need a recording setup using **AFFORDABLE** equipment that will capture thumping and slamming sounds what i hear in my room.

**DESCRIPTION:**

Sounds appear randomly and may propagate (I assume) through my walls and floor.
The sounds by order of annoyance are

- thumping (kid running in the corridor),
- door slamming,
- dog barking

The sounds are very clear to me and my wife  but for whatever reasons (you can explain me) I am having difficulty getting a good recording. I tried to record without success using

- the dictaphone of my iphone 5S left on the floor
- A ps2 singstar microphone plugged (USB) to my laptop and post-processed with Audacity ( Gain + low pass filter)

**SETUP QUESTIONS**

I am very confused on what to buy **and why**.

- Dynamic versus condenser microphone (large or small diaphragm ?) versus contact microphone on the floor ?
- Many post suggest a condenser microphone (best cheap ones seem to be Behringer B-1 or Audio-Technica AT2020) but when i read some articles i found that "Dynamic microphones are best used for booming sounds and powerful vocals."
- Omnidirectional or Cardioid ?
- Do i need a preamp or any type of supplementary equipment between the micro and my laptop ?
- What kind of post-processing should i performed and with what DAW ?

Thank you in advance. Please consider that i am not a sound engineer with many years of expertise. Just looking for a decent solution :)

best

Comment: So where should i post it then. I am asking for technical advice related to audio recording

Comment: Unfortunately  i want to record some sounds that are considered a nuisance by many but seem very difficult to capture with adequate setup, so i thought this forum of expert would be the best choice

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin but  i am not even sure  the nuisance i want to record are in this frequency range

Comment: If you can feel it as vibration, then, yes, it's waay down the low end of the spectrum, far below anything an off-the-shelf amateur setup will capture. The linked question is totally different, but the info underneath may help you.

Comment: Thx. I read this post previously but i doesnt  really adress my question:  Will I be able to record thumping and slamming door sound with a decent condenser microphone (if  it is the good type to choose), do i need some additional equipment too ?.  Like many I am not able to afford professional or  scientific grade microphone ( e.g., to record earthquakes)

Comment: Also even if i can feel it sometimes as vibration  ( it is not common), the sound is perfectly clear to my ear so it is not just very low frequency sound and i hope being able to record it